# Using an indexed field for selecting a set of random items from a collection (MongoDB)

Tags: mongodb, sorting, random, indexing, skip

I am using MongoDB 2.4.10, and I have a collection of four million records, and a query that creates a subset of no more than 50000 even for our power users. I need to select a random 30 items from this subset, and, given the potential performance issues with skip and limit (especially when doing it 30 times with random skip amounts from 1-50000), I stumbled across the following solution:

- Create a field for each record which is a completely random number
- Create an index over this field
- Sort by the field, and use skip(X).limit(30) to get a page of 30 items that, while consecutive in terms of the random field, actually bear no relation to each other. To the user, they seem random.

My index looks like this:

```
{a: 1, b: 1, c: 1, d: 1}
```

I also have a separate index:

```
{d : 1}
```

'd' is the randomised field.

My query looks like this:

```
db.content.find({a : {$in : ["xyz", "abc"]}, b : "ok", c : "Image"})
.sort({d : 1}).skip(X).limit(30)
```

When the collection is small, this works perfectly. However, on our performance and live systems, this query fails, because instead of using the a, b, c, d index, it uses this index only:

```
{d : 1}
```

As a result, the query ends up scanning more records than it needs to (by a factor of 25). So, I introduced hint:

```
db.content.find({a : {$in : ["xyz", "abc"]}, b : "ok", c : "Image"})
.hint({a : 1, b : 1, c : 1, d : 1}).sort({d : 1}).skip(X).limit(30)
```

This now works great with all values of X up to 11000, and explain() shows the correct index in use. But, when the skip amount exceeds 11000, I get:

```
{
    "$err" : "too much data for sort() with no index.  add an index or specify a smaller limit",
    "code" : 10128
}
```

Presumably, the risk of hitting this error is why the query (without the hint) wasn't using this index earlier. So:

1. Why does Mongo think that the sort has no index to use, when I've forced it to use an index that explicitly includes the sorting field at the end?
2. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: This is just a random guess (and I may in fact be wrong) but when you `hint`, aren't you hinting the index to be used for the `find()` and not the `sort()`? Also, can you include the output of `explain()` in your answer?

Comment: Can you please attach the explain plan for the query? Is there a reason for using skip() and is it structured in any specific way of ordering that can use the query filter to filter out the skipped records instead of using skip?